# "class is a reserved identifier" what is wrong in my javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am try using prototype javascript framework. i have next code

```
CheckBoxSlider = Class.create({
    initialize: function (checkbox, block) {
        this.checkbox= $(checkbox);
        this.block=$(block);
        this.checkbox.observe("click", this.onClick.bind(this));
    },
    onClick: function (event) {
        alert("Hello"); 
    }
});
window.onload= function() {
   tmp = new CheckBoxSlider("register-new-user","regiser-new-user-fields");
};
```

But on click after alert i got error "class is a reserved identifier"
What is wrong?

Sorry it's my mistake. The script works fine, the problem was in html

Comment: Apparently the fact that [class is a reserved identifier](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you forgot to load the prototype scripting, or loaded the prototype script *after* your own scripting? Your snippet is working in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/gDHK6/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "Class" is a reserved identifier - i.e. you can't use it for your own classes or variables.